# Flask to get the check box values

Tags: flask

I have below HTML page:
[image: HTMenter image description hereL]
Now using in flask I was able to find the values of whether the checkboxes are ON/OFF.
[image: Values from the HTML]
If you notice 2 values for checkboxes are marked ON which is right. But I wanted to know for which row the check box values are ON.  I'm using `request.form.getlist` to get each column values. So, using this formula there is no way I'm able to trace ON is for transportation_type cars, bike,car-pool, or WFH. Is there any easier way to find or make a relationship between chosen one as transportation type with the check box? is there any way the check value instead of ON can be an index of the row number e.g here 2, 3 assuming 1 starts.

This is a dynamically built html table:

```
<tr id="rowToClone">
            <td id="Transportation_Type">
                <select id="Transportation_Type" onChange="checkOption(this)" name="transportation_type">
                    {% for type in transportation_type %}
                        <option value="{{ type.type }}">{{ type.type }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="License_Plate" name="License_Plate" placeholder="Optional" style="text-align:center;"></td>

            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Electric"></td>
            <td id="Number of days per week" >
                <select name="DaysPerWeek">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" name="DistanceInKm" style="text-align:center;"></td>
```

if you notice, for each transportation type there is one checkbox that is either on/off. In flask check box don't send any data if they are not checked. So, I have no idea which rows send or checked the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one input with the specified name, you don't need to use **`getlist`**; just use **`get`**.

**A simple runnable example**

from flask import Flask, request

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form.getlist('hello'))

    return '''<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="hello" value="world" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="hello" value="davidism" checked>
<input type="submit">
</form>'''

app.run()
```

Comment: thanks but this is not what I'm looking after.  I wanted to know which row select my checkbox ? I have updated my initial question.